# Distributed session solution with jetty

Tags: session, jetty, distributed

I am looking into a distributed, replicated session store for multiple Jetty instances. There will be a load balancer (probably [nginx](http://nginx.org/) and/or [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)) in front of the Jetty instances.

Specifically, I would like to:

- Be able to restart (or crash) one single Jetty instance and have our services available and users still logged in.
- Be able to restart (or crash) one single session store instance and have our services available and users still logged in.

The number of sessions will most likely fit on one single machine.

What solutions do you recommend for this? What are your expieriences? Please vote for your favourite option below.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [Terracotta session clustering implementation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Session+Clustering+with+Terracotta). Haven't tried it myself, but it seems to fit my needs.

Comment: did you implement Terracotta ? curious to know if you did any comparative analysis on other such frameworks..

Comment: No. I modified https://github.com/victori/jetty-session-cache to support Infinispan. The code is unfortunately available online and since then I have changed employer.